# Suzankas Riddle

Tags: riddle, letters

[image: Suzankas Riddle]

Here is a puzzle I have been trying to solve for a long time. It was given at work as a monthly puzzle but the solutions were never released.

Comment: apparently rot13(Tbbtyrqq Plzeh vf Plzenrt sbe Abegurea Jnyrf) , if there is any cultural link later ...

Comment: Maybe you can use the Welsh alphabet to order the characters. The equations seem very arbitrary.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I can resurrect this unsolved puzzle, I believe I have an answer:

> N + L = **A**

At first I wondered whether the answer would be:

> E, since the answers appeared to be spelling out 'WALES' and the question's blurb points to North Wales (Gogledd Cymru).

However, I could not come up with a way to make this work, so I'm pretty sure it's a red herring. Instead, I then noticed a different set of connections...

*P + L = W*

> The internet country code for Poland is .pl and its capital, Warsaw, begins with W.

*T + R = A*

> The internet country code for Turkey is .tr and its capital, Ankara, begins with A.

*P + E = L*

> The internet country code for Peru is .pe and its capital, Lima, begins with L.

Which means that for *N + L = ?*, we equivalently have:

> the internet country code for the Netherlands (.nl) so the answer could be the first letter of its capital, Amsterdam i.e. A.

A pointer towards this solution might be:

> The blurb's mention of 'riddles and *code*', which could point towards *country internet **codes***...

I realise you and your colleagues have probably moved on from this question a long time ago but hopefully this answer might provide some closure to this unanswered puzzle if you agree my solution might be correct! :)